# Possible to use regex in SQL statement to filter numbers from strings?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Consider the following "tweets" (left) and "retweets" (right) tables:

```
  +----------+-----------------+     +----------+----+
  | tweet_id |  text           |     | tweet_id | rt |
  +----------+-----------------+     +----------+----+
  |  1       | foo {RT|123} bar|     |  1       | 123|
  |  2       | foobar          |     |  3       | 456|
  |  3       | {RT|456} baz    |     |  4       | 789|
  |  4       | bazbar {RT|789} |     +----------+----+
  |  5       | bar baz         |
  +----------+-----------------+
```

The tweets table contains millions of preprocessed tweets. In some tweets, a custom label is added of the form {RT|xx} **with xx being a 17 to 20 figure number**. The retweets table is currently empty, but it needs to be filled as demonstrated: tweets.text should be scanned for {RT|xx} labels, and if found, the number should be extracted from the label and inserted into the retweets table together with the tweet_id.

To do this, I started off with selecting all tweets that have {RT}-labels:

```
SELECT * FROM tweets WHERE `text` LIKE '%{RT|%'
```

A second step would be to loop through the resultset in PHP and filter the number from the label using a regular expression, and then perform an INSERT INTO operation. This, however, would take a lot of time - making me wonder if this would perhaps be faster with a SQL query? And if so, what would the query have to look like? I have never worked with regular expressions in SQL statements before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your database if MySQL, you can do it using a simple query:

```
INSERT INTO `retweets` SELECT id, SUBSTR(`text`, LOCATE('{RT|', `text`)+4, LOCATE('}', `text`) - LOCATE('{RT|', `text`)-4) AS `num` FROM `tweets` HAVING `num` REGEXP '^[0-9]+$';
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't understand the "+4"? The number in the label could be of any length, for instance a tweet could be "hello {RT|12} world {RT|43653465} this is {RT|13253453534543543}a string with{RT|13}examples". Also notice there *might* not be a space in front or after the label, but nothing (meaning: label is at beginning of string) or another character ({RT|342}foo)

Comment: +4 is length of '{RT|' prefix string!

Comment: Wow, this worked brilliantly...only a minute or two...would have taken hours and hours with my initial PHP-based, cronjob approach :-) thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe like this (untested);

```
SELECT SUBSTR(
    `text`,
    LOCATE('{RT|', `text`) + 4,
    LOCATE('}', `text`, LOCATE('{RT|', text) )
)
FROM `tweets`
WHERE `text` LIKE '%{RT|%';
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work in oracle:

```
SELECT tweet_id, REGEXP_SUBSTR(REGEXP_SUBSTR(text, '[{RT|][^}]+'), '[[:digit:]]+') FROM tweets WHERE text LIKE '%{RT|%'
```